# Google Places API - Finding nearest place, it's distance and travel time

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

With the example below,

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search

I could get a list of stores nearby to pyrmont but i would also like to get the info of the store's distance from pyrmont and the approximate travel time by car & walk. 
How could i get those info?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll probably want to use the [Distance Matrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix) and/or [Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)

Comment: Ok will have a look. Some extra web service calls though...
Thanks for the info.